# Replace characters from a string

Tags: javascript

How is it possible, to replace `ŐŰőű` characters to `ÖÜöü` in javascript?

This function only replaces the first `Ő` character:

```
str.replace('Ő','ö');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions

```
str = str
   .replace(/Ő/g,'ö')
   .replace(/Ű/g,'Ü')
   .replace(/ő/g,'ö')
   .replace(/ű/g,'ü')
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bUNxd/)**

Answer (score 4):

Use regexp and global:

```
str.replace(/Ő/g,'ö')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use regex (as provider by Claudio Redi) or use global flag 'g':

```
str.replace("Ő", "ö", "g")
str.replace("Ű", "Ü", "g")
str.replace("ő", "ö", "g")
str.replace("ű", "ü", "g")
```

see [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

I personally prefer regex. Takes some time to learn them, but it is worth it.

Comment: I agree, regex is definitely worth taking the time to learn :-)